# When I post a GitHub Page repo, the styling and images are gone: why?

Tags: github

I am trying to post something in the repository in GitHub, but when I post a website, the styling is completely gone.

GitHub link: https://github.com/Haarun45/NewsLetter-Footer

Answer (score 0):

Try and put your `index.html` and `style.css` which are in [`NewsLetter-Footer/NewsLetter Footer`](https://github.com/Haarun45/NewsLetter-Footer/tree/85eae64c3d30033a86eead8e2cedaf76442201d5/NewsLetter%20Footer) directly in the [`NewsLetter-Footer`](https://github.com/Haarun45/NewsLetter-Footer) main folder.

Or try and address `style.css` with the path from the repository root folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="NewsLetter Footer/styles.css">
```